# how to solve this error jest-worker@27.0.0-next.5:The engine "node" is incompatible with this module

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, next.js, yarnpkg

```
linix@linix-HP-ProBook-6475b:~/projects/builds$ npx create-next-app hellochat
npx: installed 1 in 2.333s
Creating a new Next.js app in /home/linix/projects/builds/hellochat.

Installing react, react-dom, and next using yarn...

yarn add v1.22.10
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error jest-worker@27.0.0-next.5: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^10.13.0 || ^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || >=15.0.0". Got "14.5.0"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom next --cwd /home/linix/projects/builds/hellochat has failed.

linix@linix-HP-ProBook-6475b:~/projects/builds$
```

Comment: Have you tried updating to Node.js `14.15.x`? As the error suggests that module isn't compatible with the current node version you are using (`14.5.0`).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to fix the problem by updating node.

**for Windows:**

just reinstall node from the .msi in Windows from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).

**for Ubuntu or Linux/Mac:**

- install module n to makes version-management easy:

`sudo npm install n -g`

- For the latest stable version:

`sudo n stable`

- For the latest version:

`sudo n latest`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had snuck in a `apt update` in my Dockerfile, which makes the system aware of the update. It's best practice to keep versions strict. For example using `'packageName': '1.0.0'` instead of `'packageName':'latest'`

I was able to solve, by removing the `apk update` and also upgrading my version of `node:alpine` to `node:alpine3.13`.